# Error while writing to text file using streamwriter in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

Hi I am writing a string from array into text file using Stream writer but getting an error "Input string was not in correct format" when it tries to write below mentioned value -

```
SET @SUBSCRIBERDISABLEDSTRING = N''del:submassemail=&quot;{Defaults:Email:MassEmails:MassEmailValue}&quot; del:suboptionsenabled=&quot;false&quot;''
```

Used different encoding (UTF8 ,ASCII) but didn't work.

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("important.txt", true, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII))
{
    try
    {
        for (int i = StartPoint; i <= EndPoint; i++)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(lines[i]);
        }
        for (int j = StartPoint1; j <= EndPoint1; j++)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(lines[j]);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that tries to write that string?

Comment: Try putting `@` before the string, e.g. `@"Hello, world!"`

Comment: @steve - added code in the post.

Comment: @Rustem - @ is not working

Comment: My crystal ball says that the real code has an extra argument in the WriteLine() call.

Comment: I can't find nothing wrong in the code above. You should try to use the debugger, check on which line you get the error message and look at the content of the offending line.

Answer (score 0):

`stream.WriteLine` seems to support formatting. `{` and `}` are control-symbols in formatting.

Maybe `lines[i].toCharArray()` will fix it?

But check the performance impact!